# How do you pass cucumber a text file of features to run? ie. rerun.txt

Tags: testing, cucumber

I finally figured out how to output failing tests to a rerun.text

cucumber -p headless --format rerun --out rerun.txt 'path of feature files'

We get the output file of rerun.txt but when we try to do

cucumber -p headless rerun.txt it gets a lexing error because gherkin can't take this input. How do we run the file in cucumber? We tried also just running:

cucumber -p headless --format rerun --out rerun.txt

with no path listed, but it will just run all the feature files. The rerun.txt does contain our failing features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the cucumber help text (`cucumber -h`):

> Use --format rerun --out features.txt to write out failing
>   features. You can rerun them with cucumber @rerun.txt.

So you'd probably want to use:

```
cucumber -p headless @rerun.txt
```

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work if there are spaces in the paths to the feature files in the rerun text file?